# I can’t recompile exo in Fedora 34

Tags: fedora, xfce, rpm, source

I have a problem with my Fedora 34.
I was trying to recompile xfce 4.12 on Fedora 34 using `rpmbuild —rebuild` from version 22 to 34, I recompiled some packages but one gave me an error which I can't repair:

> ERROR: ambiguous python shebang in /usr/lib64/xfce4/exo-1/exo-Composteli-mail-1: #!/usr/bin/python -tt. Change it to python3 (or python2) explicitly. mangling shebang in /usr/bin/exo-preffered-applications from /bin/sh to #!/usr/bin/sh

Comment: It looks as if the error message includes both the cause of the error and instructions about how to go for how to fix it.

Comment: Yeah, but it is an sourcerpm, all of source files are in this file, or in temp, the /usr/lib64/exo... doesn't exist, cause it is in the temp during the instalation process

Comment: This process is building an binary file, no install binary to the disk, you should understand i think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says what you need to do: change `/usr/lib64/xfce4/exo-1/exo-compose-mail-1` (the check actually runs at the very end of the build so this is path where the RPM you are building will install the file with the wrong shebang) to use either `#!/usr/bin/python3` or `#!/usr/bin/python2` explicitly, [since Fedora 30](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/Make_ambiguous_python_shebangs_error) `rpmbuild` checks files in the RPM and using `#!/usr/bin/python` shebang without version is considered error -- you are rebuilding SRPM from Fedora 22 where this wasn't enforced, so the build will fails because of this.

You can use the special `pathfix.py` script (from `python3-devel`) to fix the shebangs during the build (this will require changing the SPEC file in the dox SRPM), see [the F30 change decription](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/Make_ambiguous_python_shebangs_error#Using_pathfix.py_to_fix_shebangs) for more details, but in this case it would be way easier to simply change it manually because the offending file is one of the "extra" sources, the `mailtoparse.py` script, so you can simply change the first line to `#!/usr/bin/python2 -tt` to make it work.

If you want to use the script, just add

```
pathfix.py -pni "%{__python2} %{py2_shbang_opts}" %{buildroot}%{_libdir}/xfce4/exo-1/exo-compose-mail-1
```

to the `%install` section after the `exo-compose-mail-1` file is installed.

Comment: Can you tell me how to use pathfix.py for my RPM? What command should I use?

Comment: And what should I add to spec file.

Comment: It's either using the `pathfix.py` script or changing the `mailtoparse.py` manually which I suggest, but if you really want to use the script, it's described in the F30 change I linked, just add `pathfix.py -pni "%{__python2} %{py2_shbang_opts}" %{buildroot}%{_libdir}/xfce4/exo-1/exo-compose-mail-1` to the `%install` section after the `exo-compose-mail-1` file is installed.

Comment: Thank you! It is working, thanks for help!